# How to load ng-table multi-select options dynamically

Tags: angular, multi-select, ngtable

I have multiSelect filter on my ng-table. My filter options are being populated from current dataset and on some conditions I load new dataset. Once I have a new dataset, I am able to see my new data in table. But my filter options are not populated.

I use filter-data directive to pass filter options (array from my controller), but I am not able to see new filter options on my page. Any idea how can I achieve it?

Here is my HTML/PUG view for td:

```
// Status
td.input-xxs.activity-status(
   data-title="'Status'"
   header-class="'activity-status'"
   filter="{'company.status': 'select-multiple'}"
   filter-data="aCtrl.statusFilterData"
   sortable="'company.status'")
   | [[aCtrl.setDisplayText(rec.company.status, aCtrl.opCompanyStatus)]
```